# TypeError from use of "|" in re.search("RE"|"RE"|"RE", string)

Tags: python, regex

According to the docs, "|" can be used to create a regular expression that matches either of the patterns separated by "|".

I am trying to use the following to see if moves contains a string that matches one of "UP""DOWN""LEFT""RIGHT":

```
moves = input("UP 9")
m = re.search("UP"|"DOWN"|"LEFT"|"RIGHT", moves)
```

But I keep getting the `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'"`.  How to fix it?

I tried looking online but there are few samples that show the use of "|" in re. Is it not commonly used for some reason?

Comment: The confusion here is that regex patterns are a mini-language of their own, so the `|` has to be part of the pattern string that `re` compiles, not part of Python.

Comment: There are actually Python modules to build regex patterns out of normal Python expressions, so you can do something like `r(r"UP") | r(r"DOWN") | r(r"LEFT") | r(r"RIGHT")`, but I don't think you want to use one of those here; I think that, until you've got the hang of creating patterns with pure string manipulation, those libraries just add confusion, and once you _have_ got the hang of it, they're only useful in really complicated cases (where you often want to use a real parser rather than `re`), but you can search PyPI if you're interested.

Comment: as an aside, don't forget that too many or statements on a regex is slow. matching is `O(n)`. If there are many words to match, you have to choose another solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is, unfortunately a typo, but the answer goes a little deeper than that.

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. It is defined for integers only, not strings. On the other hand, the `"|"` character (note the quotes) is the regex *OR* pipe, and is used to specify a conjunction on patterns.

In summary, the `|` needs to be inside the pattern string, not outside.

```
m = re.search("UP|DOWN|LEFT|RIGHT", moves)
```

For more information on the various constructs available in regular expression mini-language, see the official [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). The subsection on [Regex Metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters), in particular (which explains the use of the OR pipe amongst others) should be helpful.